# I have a Point-in-Time SQL insert prodecure that requires some speed up

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two SQL insert procedures in Azure Data Factory. First one is to insert changes and the second is for inserting new rows in case they are found to be not existing in the new CSV files. Especially the second insert procedure is too slow of a process.

As background, there are around 50-100 thousand daily rows in the dbo.reservations2 table. And the tables that are inserted into vary between 200 thousand to 2 million rows. Currently, the first procedure takes around 2,5 minutes which is most certainly ok. But the second one seems to take multiple hours. The required speed for the second one would be under one hour.

To further specify there are 3 types of time horizons coming in, one with 7 days, second with 14 days and last with 30 days to the future. The 30 days update only comes ones a day, 14 days ones an hour and the 7 days every 15 minutes. For the 30 days update, there is a timeslot where nothing else happens for around 1,5 hours each morning

I have tried the following indexes, not sure though if they help. At least the second one actually slowed down the insertion of first procedure when testing (even though Explain capability of Azure data studio did suggest it).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX reservations_date_custom on dbo.reservations2 (datetime) include (dv_id, dv_datahash, id, unit, room, duration, specialist, specialisation1, specialisation2, specialisation3, timetype)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX reservations_date_custom2 on dbo.reservations2 (datetime) include (dv_datahash, dv_load_time, id)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX staging_id on staging.reservations (id)
```

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dv_insert]
AS
INSERT INTO 
dbo.reservations2 (
    dv_id, 
    dv_datahash, 
    dv_load_time, 
    dv_expir_time,
    id, 
    unit,
    room, 
    datetime, 
    duration, 
    specialist, 
    specialisation1, 
    specialisation2, 
    specialisation3,
    timetype, 
    reserved
) 
SELECT 
    dv_id, 
    dv_datahash, 
    dv_load_time, 
    dv_expir_time,
    id, 
    unit,
    room, 
    datetime, 
    duration, 
    specialist, 
    specialisation1, 
    specialisation2, 
    specialisation3,
    timetype, 
    reserved
FROM (
    SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', UPPER(ISNULL(id, '-1'))), 2) AS dv_id,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', UPPER(ISNULL(CAST(id AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(unit AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(room AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(datetime AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(duration AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(specialist AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(specialisation1 AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(specialisation2 AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(specialisation3 AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(timetype AS nvarchar(max)), '-1') + '~' + ISNULL(CAST(reserved AS nvarchar(max)), '-1'))), 2)  AS dv_datahash, 
    GETDATE() AS dv_load_time, 
    null as dv_expir_time,
    id AS id, 
    unit AS unit, 
    room AS room, 
    datetime AS datetime, 
    duration AS duration, 
    specialist AS specialist, 
    specialisation1, 
    specialisation2, 
    specialisation3,
    timetype AS timetype, 
    reserved AS reserved  
    FROM staging.reservations2) t1 
WHERE t1.dv_datahash NOT IN (
    Select dv_datahash
    From (Select dv_datahash, row_number() over(partition by id order by dv_load_time desc) as ranking
        from dbo.reservations2
        Where datetime >= (Select min([datetime]) from staging.reservations2)) as t2
    Where t2.ranking = '1'
)
```

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dv_insert_deleted]
AS
INSERT INTO 
dbo.reservations2 (
    dv_id, 
    dv_datahash, 
    dv_load_time, 
    dv_expir_time,
    id, 
    unit,
    room, 
    datetime, 
    duration, 
    specialist, 
    specialisation1, 
    specialisation2, 
    specialisation3,
    timetype, 
    reserved
) 
SELECT 
    dv_id, 
    dv_datahash, 
    dv_load_time, 
    dv_expir_time,
    id, 
    unit,
    room, 
    datetime, 
    duration, 
    specialist, 
    specialisation1, 
    specialisation2, 
    specialisation3,
    timetype, 
    reserved
FROM (
    SELECT 
    dv_id,
    dv_datahash, 
    Getdate() AS dv_load_time, 
    null as dv_expir_time,
    id, 
    unit, 
    room, 
    datetime, 
    duration, 
    specialist, 
    specialisation1, 
    specialisation2, 
    specialisation3,
    timetype, 
    2 AS reserved  
    FROM dbo.reservations2) t3
    WHERE t3.[datetime] >= (Select min([datetime]) from staging.reservations2)
    AND t3.[datetime] <= (Select max([datetime]) from staging.reservations2)
    AND t3.id NOT in(
        SELECT distinct id
        FROM staging.reservations2)
    AND t3.id Not in(
        Select id
        From (Select reserved, id, row_number() over(partition by id order by dv_load_time desc) as ranking
            from dbo.reservations2
            Where datetime >= (Select min([datetime]) from staging.reservations2)
            AND datetime <= (Select max([datetime]) from staging.reservations2)) as t2
        Where t2.ranking = '1'
        AND reserved = '2')
```

Comment: This is not [tag:mysql] syntax, it's [tag:sql-server]. I fixed your tags.

Comment: _"creating some trouble"_ is not a problem description. What is the problem? Are these examples running too slowly? How slowly? How fast do they need to be?

Comment: Hey, there is around 50-100 thousand daily rows in the dbo.reservations2 table. And the tables that are inserted into vary between 200 thousand to 2 million rows. Currently the first procedure takes around 2,5 minutes which is most certainly fine. But the second one seems to take multiple hours.

The required speed for the second one would be under one hour.

Comment: To further specify there are 3 types of timehorisons coming in, one with 7 days, second with 14 days and last with 30 days to the future. The 30 days update only comes ones a day, 14 days ones a hour and the 7 days every 15 minutes. For the 30 days update there is a timeslot where nothing else happens for around 1,5 hours each morning.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't be a complete answer, but I'd start with doing something else with these lines.

```
Select min([datetime]) from staging.reservations2

Select max([datetime]) from staging.reservations2
```

From your previous responses it sounds like this is a large table so getting the min and max dates several times may be part of the issue. If you run those two queries, how long do they take? If they take long, reducing them to one call each should help you out some. You can assign the values to a variable and then reference that variable in the rest of your query.

The second thought I have is have you considered refactoring the query and leverage a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? The level of nested queries on a large table like this makes me nervous for performance reasons. CTE may help you narrow down the data you need to select from and then join from the CTE to get the output columns you need. You can have one CTE join to another CTE if necessary.